# Persisting User Data with securesocial in Play 2.3 Java

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, persistence, securesocial

I am attempting to create a Java application using Play 2.3 and the master snap-shot of securesocial that will allow users to login using either Facebook , Google+ or Twitter the allow users to link their accounts together and persist this information to a database . I have been having trouble writing a UserService (particularly when linking accounts) that will allow for this. I have found examples using earlier versions of Play/securesocial but have been unable to find an example using the master snap-shot.

If anyone has any examples they could share it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create the UserService.

User Model

```
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Model {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   public Long id;

   public Date lastLogin;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   public List<Profile> identities;

   public User(Profile profile){

       identities = new ArrayList<Profile>();
       this.identities.add(profile);
       lastLogin = new Date();
   }

   public static Finder<String ,User> find = new Finder<String, User>(String.class, User.class);


}
```

Profile Model

```
 import play.db.ebean.Model;
import securesocial.core.BasicProfile;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "profiles")
public class Profile extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public String providerId;
    public String authUserId;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String fullName;
    public String email;
    public String avatarUrl;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    public User user;

    public Profile(BasicProfile profile){
        this.providerId = profile.providerId();
        this.authUserId  = profile.userId();
        if(profile.firstName().isDefined())
            firstName = profile.firstName().get();

        if(profile.lastName().isDefined())
            lastName  = profile.lastName().get();
        if(profile.fullName().isDefined())
            fullName = profile.fullName().get();
        if(profile.email().isDefined())
            email = profile.email().get();
        if(profile.avatarUrl().isDefined())
            avatarUrl = profile.avatarUrl().get();


    }
}
```

And the User Service

```
package services;
import models.Profile;
import models.User;
import play.libs.F;
import securesocial.core.BasicProfile;
import securesocial.core.PasswordInfo;
import securesocial.core.java.BaseUserService;
import securesocial.core.java.Token;
import securesocial.core.services.SaveMode;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class DemoUserService extends BaseUserService<User> {

    @Override
    public F.Promise<User> doSave(BasicProfile basicProfile, SaveMode saveMode) {
     User result = null;
     if(saveMode == SaveMode.SignUp()){
         Profile profile = new Profile(basicProfile);
         result = new User(profile);
         profile.user = result;
         result.save();
     }else if(saveMode == SaveMode.LoggedIn()){
         List<User> users = User.find.all();
         for(User user: users){
             for(Profile p : user.identities) {
                 if (p.authUserId.equals(basicProfile.userId()) && p.providerId.equals(basicProfile.providerId())) {
                    result = user;
                    result.lastLogin = new Date();
                    result.update();
                 }
             }
         }
     }else{
         throw new RuntimeException("Unknown mode");
     }
     return F.Promise.pure(result);
    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<User> doLink(User user, BasicProfile basicProfile) {
        User target;
        User u = User.find.byId(user.id.toString());
        if(u == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cant find user");
        }
        target = u;


        boolean linked = false;
        for(Profile p : target.identities){
            if(p.authUserId.equals(basicProfile.userId()) && p.providerId.equals(basicProfile.providerId())){
                linked = true;
            }
        }
        if(!linked) {
            target.identities.add(new Profile(basicProfile));
            target.update();
        }

        return F.Promise.pure(target);
    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<BasicProfile> doFind(String providerId, String userId) {
        BasicProfile found = null;
        List<User> users = User.find.all();
        for(User u: users){
            for(Profile i : u.identities){
                if(i.providerId.equals(providerId) && i.authUserId.equals(userId)){
                    found = new BasicProfile(providerId , userId , null , null , null , null , null , null , null , null , null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return F.Promise.pure(found);
    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<BasicProfile> doFindByEmailAndProvider(String s, String s1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<Token> doSaveToken(Token token) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<Token> doDeleteToken(String s) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteExpiredTokens() {

    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<Token> doFindToken(String s) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<PasswordInfo> doPasswordInfoFor(User user) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public F.Promise<BasicProfile> doUpdatePasswordInfo(User user, PasswordInfo passwordInfo) {
        return null;
    }
}
```